# JWT authentication between Django and Vue.js

Tags: django, vue.js, django-rest-framework

I wish to create a public area on a website containing standard Django and templates. When a user logs in to the members area, they are logged in to a SPA (using [Vue.js](https://vuejs.org/)) and [Django Rest Framework](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/). I will be using JWT's to handle authentication between the SPA and backend once the user has logged in to the members area.

This is the user journey:

1. User browses around the public areas of the site (served by normal Django and templates).
2. User decides to signup / login to the members area.
3. Django Rest Framework generates a JWT for the user and returns the token along with the `index.html` of the SPA
4. The user continues to use the SPA with the JWT

Is the above possible and how would it be done? More specifically, the issue is that the user is not logging in to the SPA and requesting a JWT. They are logging in to regular Django and getting returned a JWT along with the SPA. That JWT would then be used from that point onwards.

Comment: Are you using `vue-cli`? Webpack, browserify, ...?

Comment: I am using `vue-cli`

Comment: I've posted the answer, it's something that I've used for laravel. It's not complete, but maybe it can help you out. I'll have to run out, and I'll answer your questions a bit later.

Comment: should the authentication be done on the regular django page or on the SPA?

Comment: Initial login or signup is through Django. The user would then get sent the SPA along with a JWT token. From that point onwards, the JWT is used. In other words, public areas of the site or standard Django including the login page. Once logged in, the SPA is used.

Comment: Hi! Have you found a solution? I'm facing the same scenario

Answer (score -2):

This is something that I've used with laravel, but the principle should be the same.

I've placed vue-cli generated code into the subfolder `frontend`.

This is trimmed content of the file `vue.config.js`, which you need to add manually to the `vue-cli` project root.

```
const path = require('path')

/*
  vue-cli is initialized in project subfolder `frontend`
  and I run `npm run build` in that sub folder
 */
module.exports = {
  outputDir: path.resolve(__dirname, '../public/'),
  /*
    https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#outputdir
    !!! WARNING !!! target directory content will be removed before building
    where js, css and the rest will be placed
   */
  assetsDir: 'assets/',
  /*
    Where `public/index.html` should be written
    - this is example for the laravel, but you can change as needed
    - .blade.php is laravel template that's served trough laravel.
      So you could inject JWT into `index.html`
    - Check https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/html-and-static-assets.html
       for the syntax before adding values
   */
  indexPath: path.resolve(__dirname, '../resources/views/index.blade.php'),
  devServer: {
    host: '0.0.0.0',
    port: 8021,
    proxy: {
      /*
        Proxy calls from
        localhost:8021/api (frontend)
        localhost:8020/api (backend)
       */
      '/api': {
        target: 'http://localhost:8020',
        changeOrigin: true,
      }
    }
  }

};
```